# Docker confusion

Tags: docker, containers

I am very interested in docker and I've read about it but I'm a bit confused with containers. When we pull for instance, the official nginx from docker hub, is it only the application or nginx comes with operating system? It seems to me that all containers come with the operating system since with docker exec -it app-name bash i can enter and make updates or install packages. This part is confusing to me because I had the idea that it was only the application and nothing else.

thank you,
sfm1977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *depends*. Most software needs some parts of the operating system to run (which can be some libraries, or utilities); in those cases, a "base" operating system is used (`Debian` or `Alpine` for the official images), so that the application can run. Although you're able to `docker exec` into such a container and start a bash/shell session, this should only be used for debugging; in general the container (`nginx`) should be considered as the *application* nginx, not as a "virtual machine with nginx installed".

Some software is statically linked and *doesn't* need additional things to be installed. For example, the [hello-world](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/22ecfe456f254d5babe6e413bed2de77cfaba047/Dockerfile) or the [traefik](https://hub.docker.com/r/containous/traefik/~/dockerfile/) image do *not* use an operating system as a base, and only contain a single binary, nothing else.

Comment: Okay, if I make a image with nginx, based on Ubuntu (FROM), which is the difference of the official image of nginx? Are the resources consumed? It is easier to image applications such as nginx, apache, mysql based on OS's.

Comment: In the official documentation of Docker, almost all Dockerizing examples uses Ubuntu os Centos OS as a base......

Comment: The documentation is to illustrate how to "Dockerize" a traditional application; we use Ubuntu or Debian as a base image to illustrate that. If you want to use an application in Docker, your main concern should be the application *itself*, and only regard the "base" images as a "requirement" to run that software. Most official images use Debian or Alpine as a base (see the official nginx image; https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/). Use the Alpine version to have a small image, or the "Debian" version if you plan to extend the official image, and have certain needs that Alpine doesn't offer

Comment: So basically; if you need nginx, use the official nginx image, and don't worry  about the base image that's used to create it; it's nginx your interested in, and the base image is just an "implementation detail"

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you call the "OS". Is you mean both `kernel space` and `user space` - answer is no. Containers change user space only.

Docker works like chroot or lxc, it uses single Linux kernel from host and binaries/libraries/etc in containers to run, containers in nutshell are isolated namespaces on single machine.
So, "OS" will never change in case if containers, but `"environmnet"` will change (libc, shells, all that stuff).
Also, check this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) article about cgroups.
PS: sure, when you're not on Linux you need to install VM with Linux to use Docker. But this is another question.

Comment: Okay, if I make a image with nginx, based on Ubuntu (FROM), which is the difference of the official image of nginx? Are the resources consumed? It is easier to image applications such as nginx, apache, mysql based on OS's.

Comment: In the official documentation of Docker, almost all Dockerizing examples uses Ubuntu os Centos OS as a base......

Comment: @SérgioMarques "OS" in case of "FROM" means `environment` used in Ubuntu image (package manager, languages versions, etc). So, difference will be in the base image chosen by maintainer. I'll recommend to use official image of whatever, coz it will be more stable and secure (bugs/CVE fixes, updates, etc). But if you want use "nginx own" image -  go ahead, you may also update this image when nginx updates and re-create containers based on it.